# Making a calendar tool with Google API. Should I use OAuth Service Account?

Tags: php, api, calendar

I'm creating a calendar tool for a client. He has his work calendars in a Google account, which I have access to. I'll be using the Google Calendar API for the tool, but I'm new to Google APIs and the OAuth stuff. I'll be using PHP. Do I need to use an OAuth2 Service Account, or should I make a regular OAuth2 Web Application Client ID from that Google account?

In case this information is helpful, the tool I will be making will do this:
1) Allow my client to fill out a form which will create a new calendar and populate it with several events.
2) Send out an email to a mailing list twice a week listing changes that have been made to these calendars.

I'll also be making a page that displays the iframes for each calendar, so his clients may see them even if they do not have a Google account.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a third party class such as [this one](https://github.com/montania/Google-Calendar-API-PHP-Class), may be a better start for you then. This is just a lightweight version, but there are more extensive ones out there. The important part is that they already implemented the hard parts for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your client who needs to authenticate with Google you should use OAuth2 or the most recent. Using tokens is much more secure than asking a client to enter their email and password.

A nice place to test API calls is http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/ this also has a link to the OAuth2 playground for API's which support it.